# Windows rdp always failed

Tags: remote-desktop

PC A:
In home ethernet
Windows10 2004 x64 pro

PC B:
In office ethernet
Windows10 1909 x64 pro

If I use android microsoft rdp, I can connect **PC A** from office network.
But if I use **PC B**, I get a black screen, then report the rdp session is over: error in connection establishment or network.

Thank those who can think about any suggestions.

1. The memory occupation of **PC A** is about 40%
2. Restart **PC A** or **PC B** seems no use

Comment: 3.PC B uses mstsc.exe failed , even after updated from 1909 to 2004. But it succeeded when trying rdp fom ms store !

Comment: 4. The mstsc.exe from PC B can connect to some other PCs, except the one in my home :(

Comment: So you can't connect from PC B to PC A, how are this two PCs connected? VPN or simple port forward from router to PC A ?